# The numbers from 1 to 1000 are each written on a slip of paper

Tags: probability

The numbers from 1 to 1000 are each written on a slip of paper and placed in a box and one slip is removed from it. What is the probability that the number drawn is a multiple of 5?

Answer (score 1):

1 in 5 numbers are divisible by 5 (200 numbers between 1 and 1000), so the probability is 20%.